# Determine the values for the common distribution table.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following common distribution table with marginal distribution.

[image]

X and Y are random variables and I need to fill in the unknowns using what I have. However, I am not sure how to do them since I feel like there are too many unknown values to complete the table properly. I think I might have to create systems of equations and try to solve it that way.

Answer (score 0):

It does look like seven equations (three rows, three columns and the total being $1$) and eight unknowns, so unlikely to have a unique solution except in a special case

Let $q = p_{0,1}$.  You can then make your table

```
X \ Y |   0      1      2   | P(X=k)
------+---------------------+------- 
   0  | 1/8      q    1/8   | 1/4+q
   1  | 1/16   1/16-q 3/8+q | 1/2
   2  | 3/16-q 1/16    0    | 1/4-q 
------+---------------------+------- 
P(Y=k)| 3/8-q  1/8    1/2+q |
```

and this will work provided that $0 \le q \le \frac1{16}$ so all the cells are non-negative